# JQuery Accessing Input feild value

Tags: jquery, input, keyboard-events

I am trying following code in JQuery, i have added two events for two buttons. One for increase by 1 and 1 for decrease by one. However decrease by one is working properly but increase by one instead of increasing value by 1 it is appending 1 in the value i.e. 1, 11, 111, 1111.
How can i fix this problem.
Am i doing anything wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("button.decreament").click(function () {
    let x = $(this).siblings("input").val()
    if (x >= 1) {
        $(this).siblings("input").val(x - 1);
    }
});

$("button.increament").click(function () {
    let x = $(this).siblings("input").val()
        $(this).siblings("input").val(x + 1);
});
```

});

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `+` is overloaded. It acts like a concatenation operator for strings. To remove this confusion, you can use it like this.

```
$(this).siblings("input").val(parseInt(x) + 1); 
or,
$(this).siblings("input").val(parseInt(x) + parseInt(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are concatenating the variables as strings and not adding the numbers. Add a `+` in front of the variable and the code will treat the variable as a number.

This should work for you => `$(this).siblings("input").val(+x + 1);`

***Here's an example snippit:***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sval = $(".value");
  var reduce = $(".reduce");
  reduce.click(function() {
    let $this = $(this).val();
    let value = sval.text();    
    $this = (+$this - 1); //<-- +$this is now treated as a number
    value = (+value - 1); //<-- +value is now treated as a number
    reduce.val($this);
    sval.text(value);
    console.log('single item reduced by 1: ' + value);
    console.log('increment increased by 1: ' + $this);
  });
  var add = $(".add");
  add.click(function() {
    let $this = $(this).val(); 
    let value = sval.text(); 
    $this = (+$this + 1); //<-- +$this is now treated as a number
    value = (+value + 1); //<-- +$value is now treated as a number  
    add.val($this);
    sval.text(value);
    console.log('single item increased by 1: ' + value); 
    console.log('increment increased by 1: ' + $this);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Decrement: <input type="button" class="reduce" value="4"> Increment: <input type="button" class="add" value="4"> Single value: <span class="value">10</span>
```